# lua in a table to get another element of the same table

Tags: lua, roblox, fivem

When creating an element in the table, I need to use another element that I created before in the same table. please help me with this.

```
local table = {
    distance = 30.0,
    last_distance = table.distance-10.0
}
```

I want to do the above operation but I can't, I think I need to use self or setmetatable but I don't know how to do it. and please don't give me answers like first create a value outside and then use it in the table, I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 3):

#### Basic life advice

First of all: Don't call your table `table`. That will shadow the global `table` library. Call it `t`, `tab`, `tabl`, `Table`, `table_`, or actually give it a useful name, but don't call it `table`, or there'll be a big surprise when you try to access any `table.*` methods. Ideally, your linter should warn you about this.

#### Implementing it using hacks

Table constructors are equivalent to creating a table *on the stack* - there is no named local variable `self` or the like. It is likely possible that there is a *hidden* local variable accessible using `debug.getlocal` however:

```lua
$ lua
Lua 5.4.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2022 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> function getlocals()
>> local i = 1; repeat local k, v = debug.getlocal(2, i); i = i + 1; print(k, v) until not k
>> t = {a = getlocals(), b = ()}
stdin:3: unexpected symbol near ')'
> function getlocals()
local i = 1; repeat local k, v = debug.getlocal(2, i); i = i + 1; print(k, v) until not k end
> t = {a = getlocals(), b = 2}
(temporary) table: 0x55e9181302d0
nil nil
> t
table: 0x55e9181302d0
```

Indeed, from basic testing it appears that this is even the first local inside the table constructor! However, it isn't quite as easy:

```lua
> local a = 1; local b = a; t = {a = getlocals(), b = 2}; print(b)
a   1
b   1
(temporary) table: 0x55e918130160
nil nil
1
```

Using extensive hacks, you might be able to write something that returns the currently constructed table *most of the time* (probably relying on the fact that it will usually be the last local). The following works:

```lua
function lastlocal()
    local i = 0
    local last
    ::next:: -- you could (and perhaps should) use a loop instead
    i = i + 1
    local k, v = debug.getlocal(2, i)
    if v then
        last = v
        goto next
    end
    return last
end
```

from my basic testing, this works fine to obtain the table currently being constructed:

```lua
> function lastlocal()
    local i = 0
    local last
    ::next:: -- you could (and perhaps should) use a loop instead
    i = i + 1
    local k, v = debug.getlocal(2, i)
    if v then
        last = v
        goto next
    end
    return last
end
> t = {a = 1, b = lastlocal().a}
> t.a
1
> t.b
1
```

#### Why you should not implement this using hacks

With all of this in mind: **Don't ever do this.** The purpose of this merely is to lead this *ad absurdum*. There are *multiple reasons* why this is *horribly unreliable*:

1. [*The order of execution of table constructor assignments is undefined*](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-06/msg00376.html). An optimizing interpreter like LuaJIT (and the PUC Lua implementation just as well) is free to reorder `{a = 1, b = 2}` to `{b = 2, a = 1}`.
2. Likewise, how table constructors are implemented internally is entirely *undefined*. There is no guarantee that the local variable actually exists and is the *last* one.
3. It is horribly inefficient and relies on the `debug` library for something other than debugging.

#### What's a metatable?

Metatables serve an entirely different purpose; you could dynamically generate derived fields like `last_distance` using them, but you can't use them to reference a table using a table constructor. Here's a basic example:

```lua
local t = {distance = 30}
setmetatable(t, {__index = function(self, k)
    if k ~= "last_distance" then return nil end
    return t.distance - 10 -- calculate `last_distance` & return it
end})
print(t.last_distance) -- 20
t.distance = 10
print(t.last_distance) -- 0
```

#### Back to the question

> When creating an element in the table, I need to use another element that I created before in the same table.

The proper way to do this is to either (1) create a value outside of the table

```lua
local distance = 30
local last_distance = distance - 10
local tab = {distance = distance, last_distance = last_distance}
```

Perfectly readable, perfectly fine.

Or (2) first create a table with some properties, then add derived properties:

```lua
local tab = {distance = 30}
tab.last_distance = tab.distance - 10
```

as readable, as fine.

Both will be highly efficient; only micro-optimizations would be debatable (could (1) choose a better layout for the hashes by choosing the right insertion order? does it pre-allocate the right size (likely yes)? does (2) incur a penalty since it indexes `tab` to obtain `tab.distance`?), but none of this will likely ever matter.

> I want to do the above operation but I can't, I think I need to use self or setmetatable but I don't know how to do it.

I have shown you:

- How you can do it using egregious hacks and why you shouldn't.
- How you can do something *similar* (derived attributes) using a metamethod.

> and please don't give me answers like first create a value outside and then use it in the table, I don't want to do that.

This is the correct, idiomatic way to do this in Lua though. Your restriction seems arbitrary.